# Graph containing a cycle of $2k$

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, and a parameter $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq 2$, how can I show that if $|E|\geq |V|^{1+\frac{1}{k}}$, a cycle $C$ exists in $G$ such that $|C|\leq 2k$?

The only initial idea I have is that as $|E|\geq |V|^{1+\frac{1}{k}}$, I know that the maximal degree of a vertex is at least $|V|^\frac{1}{k}$. But I fail to see how I reach a cycle, let alone one of a specific length (at least) $2k$.

I have also been hinted that $\frac{|V|^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}{2}$ edges should suffice, but seems to be hard for me to tackle as well.

Answer (score 2):

I can prove the claim for graphs with  $|E| \ge |V|^{1+ 1/k} + |V|$

Let $n = |V|$ and $m=|E|$ and $D = \left\lceil n^{\frac{1}{k}} \right\rceil$.
As long as $G$ contains a vertex $v$ with degree at most $D$, delete $v$. You are left with a graph $G'$ in which all vertices have degree at least $D+1$.

The graph $G'$ cannot be empty, since otherwise the  number of edges in $G$ would be at most $n \cdot D < n \cdot (n^{\frac{1}{k}} + 1) = n^{1+1/k} + n$.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $G$, and hence $G'$, contains no cycle of length at most $2k$ and let $s$ be an arbitrary vertex of $G'$. Build a BFS tree $T$ of $G'$ rooted in $s$, and recall that the depths (in $T$) of the endvertices of all non-tree edges differ by most $\pm 1$.

Then all vertices at depth at most $k-1$ in $T$ have no incident non-tree edge (since otherwise there would be a cycle of length at most $(k-1) + 1 + k = 2k$).

The root of $T$ has at least $D+1$ children, and every other vertex at depth $1, \dots, k-1$ has at least $D$ children. Hence the number of nodes of $T$ is:
$$
1 + (D+1) \sum_{i=1}^{k} D^{i-1} = 1 + (D+1) \frac{D^k - 1}{D-1} > D^k \ge n,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very interesting! I followed up until each level $x$ in $T$ has $n^x$ vertices. Why is the height of the tree limited to $k-1$? I think it can be $k$, which is very problematic for the proof's ending. The sum of the number of vertices up to (including) $k-1$ level is at least $n^{\frac{k-1}{k}}$. Only if we go to height $k$ do we have enough vertices, but then inner edged between $2$ level $k$ vertices may arise.

Comment: If the tree had height $k$ or more then the number of vertices at depth (exactly) $k$ would be at least $n^\frac{k}{k} = n$ (since there are no non-tree edges incident to vertices at depth at most $k-1$), and the number of vertices at depth **at most** $k$ would be strictly larger than $n$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: See also the edited answer which takes into account the fact that $n^{1/k}$ might not be an integer. Unfortunately this loses a $+n$ on the number of edges.